# How to use Microsoft MIP SDK from Python?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, microsoft365, microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

I'm building an app that automatically labels Office files on Windows computers. To apply my sensitivity labels to documents programmatically, Microsoft tells me to use its [MIP SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/setup-configure-mip).

But the SDK is in C++, with some convoluted async Observer patterns, so it's not clear to me how to call its functions from Python.

Has anyone succeeded in using the MIP SDK with Python 3? **Can you share a concrete Python example of calling the `SetLabel()` function on a file?**

Comment: Have you looked at using [Python Bindings](https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview) to invoke the MIP calls?

Answer (score 1):

I have spent sometime looking into this problem.  Microsoft doesn't make it clear on how to call their MIP `C++` code using `Python`.  It's also unclear for me if you're trying to set sensitivity labels on local Office files or ones stored in SharePoint or in Office 365.

I previously mentioned using Python Bindings, but after doing some research there are other ways.

**Technique One**

---

`Microsoft` has a `PowerShell` framework called [Security & Compliance Center PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/scc-powershell?view=exchange-ps).  One the cmdlet is [Set-Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant?view=sharepoint-ps), which can be used to enable sensitivity labels for Office files.  There is another module called [Set-LabelPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-labelpolicy?view=exchange-ps) that can assist in setting global sensitivity
policies.

`PowerShell` cmdlet can be called from `Python`. There are lots of examples on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell+python) on how to accomplish this.

**Technique Two**

---

Again Microsoft really requires you to dig for information to use `Python` over their prefer coding languages.

Microsoft has a `GitHub` project called [AutoRest Python](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.python).  This project generates `Python` code that is needed to interact with Microsoft Information Protection (MIP) and other Microsoft centric products.

The other `GitHub` project that is needed is [msrest for python](https://github.com/Azure/msrest-for-python).

If you dig through some of [Microsoft GitHub repositories](https://github.com/orgs/Azure/repositories?q=python&type=&language=&sort=) you will find examples on how to use these modules.

**Technique Three**

---

You can also use `Python` to set registry settings related to sensitivity labels for Office files.  If needed I can provide you the registry keys.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Nor does it meet the requirements for my bounty award, which were very clear. No idea why it was auto-selected and accepted :(

Comment: Thanks for responding to this post-bounty question 30 days after I posted an answer.  The question was auto-selected for 50% of the bounty, because of the Stack Overflow rules on awarding bounties.  I'm sorry that you disagree with the established rules.

Comment: No problem. I still need the answer though :( Maybe another bounty?

Comment: I understand.  I will look through my answer again, because I know that the answer is within the examples.  My issue is being able to test the code, because I don't have a Windows environment.

Comment: @user124114 are you trying to set the labels on individual files stored in a local file system of a specific computer or are you trying to find a certain file containing specific information stored in multiple systems across the entire enterprise?

Comment: The former – I'm building an app that automatically labels Office files on Windows computers. So I need to call `setLabel()` on a local file, yes.